.NET JWT bearer verification not handled by the framework
Why is that despite having the .well-known/openid-configuration specified in .NET auth settings - we still need to provide the all the information manually?
I my auth flow - the RSA asymmetric encryption is used for JWT tokens and Web API application needs to validate the token. JWT is issued by Keycloak..
The JWT header example:
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT",
  "kid": "LSx-RczcXcqiEwgBZuOCcSc91QfNg7u2fnPGDUhzxac"
}

Keycloak provides the realm's .well-known/openid-configuration out of the box. It contains the issuer, as well as some other endpoints for data querying. I would also assume that the RSA public key is also publicly discoverable in some way.
The problem is - that it's not enough to specify the following config in .NET
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
        .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "http://host.docker.internal:7080/realms/master"; 
            options.MetadataAddress = "http://host.docker.internal:7080/realms/master/.well-known/openid-configuration";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        };

This code will fail to validate the incoming JWT token and complain about the authority validation failure, as well as signing key validation failure!
The working code is:
string publicKey = "your public key goes here";

var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsa.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(Convert.FromBase64String(publicKey), out _);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
        .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                RequireSignedTokens = true,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:7080/realms/master",
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = "account",
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new RsaSecurityKey(rsa),
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidAlgorithms = new[]
                {
                    "RS256"
                }
            };
        });

It seems counter intuitive to provide the IssuerSigningKey as well as the ValidIssuer manually.
To me it looks like all of this information is available in the metadata and the framework should be able to discover and handle it by itself.
Which leads me to believe that I have a fundamentally wrong understanding of either the well-known endpoint purpose or the framework expected logic.
Could someone please clarify what is the correct use-case for the well known endpoint and why the framework is not handling the request validation in a more automated way given that it has a knowledge of the JWT encryption algorithm and the metadata.

try to see if you can enable "oidc" since that discovery endpoint is not part of the base oauth2 flow. Also, you want to declare the valid issuer. Otherwise, I will create a token an write myself as issuer as well as provide you with a discovery endpoint confirming I am the right one.  Settings look ok in general, but yes, try to replace the hard coded key with code oidc enable setting.

This is because you are missing your claims. In the claims make sure to pass like this as below.
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));

Then it should work.

Sorry I don't understand your proposed solution. Where should I put the claims to and what do they solve?

Hey you can add this to the place where you are making the claims. The place where you are creating the token.
